# Groupby a column value for 2 hour

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I have a data frame with columns Date, Time, Distance. I want to groupby distance column for each day with 2 hours interval. I have checked the question asked in stack overflow, but it is not giving me the required output.

The sample code I have pasted is from stack overflow, but the output is not as desired.

```
uniquedate = np.unique(df2["Date"])
for i in uniquedate:
    data_new1 = df2[df2['Date']==i]
    data_new2 = data_new1[['Real_time', 'Distance_km']].copy()
    data_new2.index = pd.to_timedelta(data_new2.index.astype(str))
    data_new2 = data_new2.resample('2H').sum()
    print(data_new2)

                 Distance_km
00:00:00.000000   276.850844
                 Distance_km
00:00:00.000000   193.115217
```

I got this output but this is not as required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data_new2.groupby([data_new2.index,pd.TimeGrouper(freq='2H')]).sum()
```

Please avoid copy pasting code from stack overflow. More often than not the solution will not suffice for your use case. Plus it's lazy.

**EDIT**
Make your index as datetime or timestamp aand then doing a simple resample should work for you.

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=5, freq='H')
ts = pd.Series(range(len(idx)), index=idx)
ts = ts.resample('2H').sum()
```

Comment: I have modified the code which i got from stack overflow. the code u gave me the following result. i can share the dataset if i have your email id     Distance_km
00:00:00.000000 00:00:00.000000     0.000000
                00:00:00.000000     0.000000
                00:00:00.000000     0.000000
                00:00:00.000000     0.000000
                00:00:00.000000     0.000000

Comment: i mean it didnt sum it up

Comment: sorry i don't know how to paste the result i got

Comment: Date--Real_time--Distance_km 24-09-2019--00:30:51--0

Comment: buddy can u share me your email id?

Comment: hey harry, i have dropped u a mail :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know if I get you right - mainly because you do not post an example of your data.

However, here's an mcve:

```
# dtrg = pd.date_range('01.Jan.1999 21:17', '02.Jan.1999 04:23', freq='10min')
# df = pd.DataFrame({'distance': np.random.randint(1, 5, len(dtrg)) * 10}, index=dtrg)

# df.head()
#                      distance
# 1999-01-01 21:17:00        30
# 1999-01-01 21:27:00        40
# 1999-01-01 21:37:00        10
# 1999-01-01 21:47:00        30
# 1999-01-01 21:57:00        30
```

with this data you could simply group by the datetime index in 2H-slices and sum up the distance:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2H')).sum()

                     distance
1999-01-01 20:00:00       140
1999-01-01 22:00:00       340
1999-01-02 00:00:00       370
1999-01-02 02:00:00       300
1999-01-02 04:00:00        40
```

---

...and if your dataframe doesn't have a datetime index but date and time as separate string values, you should transform them to datetime and set that as index before:

example dataframe structure:

```
         date   time  distance
0  01.01.1999  09:00        10
```

transform date and time columns to datetime index:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.date.str.cat(df.time, sep=' '))).distance

date
1999-01-01 09:00:00    10
Name: distance, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I have a separate column for the date and time. I want to share the data, but while pasting the format changes

Comment: Date--Real_time--Distance_km
24-09-2019--00:30:51--0